# Aerial mounting broken on '95 Peugeot 106

Tags: peugeot

**Short story:** I parked below a tree. When I backed out of the parking spot the aerial got stuck in a branch an the *aerial mounting* snapped (aerial was forced forward, mounting bracket gave in). The aerial itself screws into the mounting bracket and was not damaged. Only the bracket (or joint — I'm not really sure what this is called).

The aerial mounting is located in the front of the roof directly above the cabin lights (inside). My suspicion is that I can remove the cabin lights from the roof in order to gain access to the aerial mounting bracket where it is attached to the roof.

[image: Aerial position]

1. Is this the case (suggested [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_Replace_roof_aerial_on_Peugeot_106))?
2. Also, will I be able to attach wiring in this location?
3. Or will I need to remove the stereo etc. in order to replace the aerial mounting and the entire wire between stereo and mounting?
4. What is the "real" part name (I guess it's not aerial mounting bracket or joint)?

Anyone with experience in this regard?

--

**UPDATE**
The part name is "*Roof Aerial Base Mount*" (#656110). I ordered mine off of eBay for appr. $12 incl. P&P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly (and if it is the same as other Peugeots of that era), there is a bolt as part of the mount that passes through a hole in the roof and is secured with a nut on the inside - this can be accessed, as you suggest, by removing the interior light.

ISTR the wire then ran down the right-hand windscreen pillar, but there was a connector up behind the headlining above the windscreen, so the aerial could be removed without having to un-thread the entire wiring - This was on a 205, so they may have changed it later...

Comment: Turns out you remembered correctly. The base was mounted with a 8mm nut which also held the wire connector. It was an easy fix :)